# How can I add URLs to crawler of crawler4j at random times during progress

Tags: java, web-crawler

I'm tackling to crawler4j.
http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/

and simple test crawl a site was succeeded.
but I want to add URLs at random times during progress.

this code shows the following exception at second constructing CrawlController.
how can I add URLs during progress? or reuse CrawlController?
(also reuse case without re-constructing CrawlController was failed.)

any idea?
or other good crawler in Java?

edit:
since it might be a bug, I posted also to the page of crawler4j. 
http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/issues/detail?id=87&thanks=87&ts=1318661893

```
private static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URI> urls = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<URI>();
...
URI uri = null;
while (true) {
    uri = urls.poll();
    if (uri != null) {
        CrawlController ctrl = null;
        try {
            ctrl = new CrawlController("crawler");
            ctrl.setMaximumCrawlDepth(3);
            ctrl.setMaximumPagesToFetch(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        ctrl.addSeed(uri.toString());
        ctrl.start(MyCrawler.class, depth);
    }else{
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:638)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.PageFetcher.startConnectionMonitorThread(PageFetcher.java:124)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlController.<init>(CrawlController.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.0, this feature is implemented in crawler4j. Please visit http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/multiple/ for an example usage.

Basically, you need to start the controller in non-blocking mode:

```
controller.startNonBlocking(MyCrawler.class, numberOfThreads);
```

Then you can add your seeds in a loop. Note that you don't need to start the controller several times in a loop.

Comment: thanks Yasser. But using above, one will not enable one to use setCustomData different for different seed ?